# How to get the exact value of this problem using loop and condition statement?

Tags: python

My aim is to calculate the accurate value of I_a using python as given in [Flow chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKMzs.jpg). I initially assume that the value of I_a=42 degree and f = 1. The value of (i) is between 0 to 100. My expected result should be I_a=43.53 degree approximately.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from numpy import sqrt, pi,tan
i=0
f=1 
R_a=1.93 
I_a=42+i 
x1=2*f*tan(I_a * pi / 180)+R_a
x2=2*f*tan(I_a * pi / 180)-R_a
l= lambda x:sqrt(1+(x/2*f)**2)
k = integrate.quad(l, x2, 2*f) 
m = integrate.quad(l,2*f,x1)  
v=k[0]-m[0]
for i in np.arange(0, 100,0.001):
 if (v<=0.01):
  print(I_a)
 else:
    i += 0.001
```

Comment: Shouldn't all the calculations (from I_a = ... to v= ...) be INSIDE the for loop ? Furthermore, I imagine you want to stop the loop there: if (v<=0.01): print("results") ; then adding `print(I_a)` and  `break` would be opportune.

Comment: Why are you incrementing `i` ?

Comment: you probably also want to print actual results, and not just the string "results"

Comment: The flow chart definitely shows performing calculations *over-and-over* until a criteria is met. Why aren't you doing that?